# Check if sub object of javascript object contains a certain string

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

If I have a TypeScript Array of

```
things: Things[]

export type Party = {
  id: string;
  name: string;
};

export type Things = {
  party: Party;
  id: number;
  ...more stuff
};
```

how can I check if the things array has a Party with a certain name?

Something like
`included = things.includes(party.name.includes("Bob"))`
or `included = things.some(party.name("Bob"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there:

```js
const included = things.some(thing => thing.party.name === "Bob")
```

You need to provide a *function* to `some`. That function will be called for every element and should return something that (when coerced to a boolean) indicates whether the element matches your criteria or not. In this case we pass a function that returns `true` if an element's `party` property has a `name` property that is equal to `"Bob"`.

Comment: Should be `thing => thing.party.name === "Bob"`

Answer (score 1):

You could use `.find`

```
const included = !!things.find(thing => thing.party.name === 'Bob')
```

P.S `!!` before the statement makes `included` as a boolean

Comment: yeah makes sense

Comment: Hm, but why do we need `!!` and `find` then? It's slower and harder to read than just `some`

Comment: @CherryDT  One possible reason might be for legacy support, eg. IE8..  But even then I'd polyfill.

Comment: @Keith https://caniuse.com/array-find - `find` isn't supported in IE either.